# ggplot2 black bar when outputting plot using bbplot theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, databricks, azure-databricks

I've started using the bbplot package today which is generally working really well, and is a theme and wrapper for ggplot2 created by the BBC. However, when finalising the plot, the exports seem to include a black bar at the bottom of the image which masks the source details. I've fiddled with the code and it seems to be happening when the subtitle or source are longer than a certain number of characters (although still less wide than the width of the available space). I can't get any plots to finalise with both a subtitle and source at present.

Using databricks in azure - Runtime 9.1 LTS

Code:

```
svannualcount <- ggplot(svkc_count, aes(x = as.character(Recorded_Year), y = n)) +
  geom_col(fill="#082a52") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1, colour="#333333") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  bbc_style() +
  labs(title="This is a test title",
       subtitle = "Can you read my test title?")

finalise_plot(plot_name = svannualcount,
              source = "Source: This is a test source.",
              save_filepath = "/tmp/svkcannualplot.png",
              width_pixels = 640,
              height_pixels = 450,
              logo_image_path = "/tmp/vrulogo.png"
             )
```

Data:

```
  Recorded_Year     n `as.character(Recorded_Year)`
          <int> <dbl> <chr>                        
1          2018  2171 2018                         
2          2015  1128 2015                         
3          2019  2128 2019                         
4          2020  2041 2020                         
5          2016  1572 2016                         
6          2017  1968 2017                         
7          2021  1711 2021
```

Image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the output of `dput(svkc_count)`, please? Like this we don't have data to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks - have added data in although dput doesn't render correctly as using R within a spark cluster

Comment: OK, I cannot reproduce this error, the plot in an RStudio session or as a file are the same. R 4.1.2 on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

On further testing and with useful input from @rui-barradas this was identified as an issue with databricks and ggplot2 plots not appearing correctly in line in a notebook. The exported plots render correctly when opened in an image browser.